# Making SVN overwrite existing files

Tags: svn

Is there a way to get SVN to overwrite an existing file thats not checked into the working directory?   Ive tried to use force but that will just complete the action without an error.

Comment: Do you mean, an unversioned file that a later commit adds, and you are trying to update to that later version? Or do you mean, a versioned file with changes, and you want to remove the changes?

Comment: the first I want to be able to overwrite and unversioned file with an update.